Generate weighted median from activity per timespan
I have a set of data where I have a number of observations over the course of a year per individual. Generally speaking, I want to know the average activeness of the individuals that participated in this project. However, not everyone completed the full year. Therefore, I have opted to use the participation days as weights to evaluate the activeness not over the whole year but over the course of participation. However, some individuals have been so extremely active that I have to consider these to be outliers. Therefore, I want to look at the median instead of the mean of the poplulation activeness.
What I have thought of so far is taking the average (mean) activeness per individual, so the mean number of observations divided by the number of participation days, and just take the median of these. However, I am not sure if that is the right way to get to the right value.
If anyone could weigh in on this and maybe give me some pointers I would be extremely thankful!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median.

Questions about code are off topic here. But there seems to also be a statistics question here. If you edit your question to emphasize that, then it is less likely to be closed.

@PeterFlom thanks for the feedback. Would StackOverflow be a more appropriate forum to ask for specific help to generate this in Excel? Will edit the question

I don't know. I rarely visit StackOverlow.
